# What is the proper way to enable tagging to all documents in a site collection

Tags: search, content-type, managed-metadata, site-column, tagging

I am using SP2013 on-premise. In order to enhance search experience, I want to enable tagging for all documents. In Site settings -> Site Content Type, I open **Document**. Then I "**add column to existing content type**" and pick a custom column XLabel, which is a custom managed metadata column I created. When I save the change, various error come out. For example:

> The content type "System Master Page" at "/" is sealed. ... The
>   content type "Page Layout" at "/_catalogs/masterpage" is sealed.
>   Reason:

I found most of document library have added XLabel column and I can search out document thru `owstaxidmetadataalltagsinfo:check`. However, I am worry what the error messages mean.

Also I have tried add a site column XLabel to document library. I think the outcome is the same but I need to add column XLabel to all document library one by one. New created document library will not have XLabel. Hence I want to directly change the content type.

Am I doing it wrong? What is the proper way to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 1):

The most common way would be to [create your own content type](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-or-customize-a-site-content-type-33eeb0b4-51c4-48a2-80d6-a8cd32b7dce1?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US), deriving from `Document` and add the custom column to this new content type. That way you would not run in to this kind of clashes with other OOTB content types that already inherits from `Document`.

This custom content type could be created and published from a [Content Type Hub](http://sharepoint-community.net/profiles/blogs/understanding-content-type-hub-cth-in-sharepoint-2013), making it available on all site collections subscribing to a specific Managed metadata service.

This means you can manage the content type from one single location.

The downside is that this content type would not automatically be added to your document libraries, so you would need to either do that manually or automate it (by for ex. using feature stapling and / or event receivers on-prem or remote-event-receivers and some provisioning logic in Online)

Comment: Just have a test and found even I modify Document content type, the change will not automatically added to existing doc lib awa new created doc lib...

Comment: Nope, as soon as you add a content type to a document library it's getting separated from the parent, not always the best behavior

Comment: Sorry, you mean add a content type is not a good behavior?